# What is the density of integers whose prime factor exponents are in order?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n = p_1^{a_1} p_1^{a_2} \cdots p_{\omega(n)}^{a_{\omega(n)}}$ be the prime factorization of $n$ for some prime $p_1, p_2, \ldots p_{\omega(n)}$ and exponents $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{\omega(n)}$. If $a_1 \ge a_2 \ge \ldots \ge a_{\omega(n)}$ we say that $n$ has descending exponents. Trivially if $n$ is square-free or $n$ is a perfect power whose exponent are the same (e.g. $2^6 3^6$) then $n$ has descending exponents. We are interested in the non-trivial cases when $n$ has two or more distinct exponents (e.g. $2^3 5^2 7^1 11^1$).

Experimental data for $n \le 10^9$ shows that the density of non-trivial numbers whose exponents are in descending order approaches $0.31403$ as $n \to \infty$.

**Question 1**: What is the density of non-trivial numbers which have descending exponents? Does the limiting value have a closed form?

**Question 2**: Is the corresponding density for ascending exponents zero?

[image]

Comment: I think that 10^9 is very small number when we want to conjecture something about prime factorization. I suggest you to consider a more precise analyze : In this range, what is the density of numbers with 3 factors ($a^2b$ has 3 factors, if $a$ and $b$ are prime), and in this subset of numbers with 3 factors, what is the density of 'winning numbers' (=numbers like $a^2b$, where $a<b$). And the same with numbers with 4 factors. Winning numbers in this case are $a^2bc$, $a^3b$).  In this scope, count the 3 options (number of $a^2b$, number of $abc$, and number of $ab^2$)

Comment: In range $<10^9$, density of numbers with 3,4, or 5 factors is very high. In some very far countries, numbers with 40 or 50 factors are preponderant, and in those countries, density of winning numbers is certainly smaller than in our countries.

Comment: @Lourrran Valid point. I am running the script in the interval $(10^{50}, 10^{50}+10^6)$ to see the density in this range. Will share the full results after a completion however; from the output so far, the density still seems to be consistently close of $0.314$ even in the neighbourhoods of this large number.

Comment: My point was that you should modelize the behavior. We know the density of numbers with 1 factor (=prime numbers), we can correctly estimate the density of numbers with 2 factors, with 3 factors, and so on. For numbers with k factors, we can estimate the density of winning numbers (for numbers with 3 factors, 33% or 40% are winning, this density may change, but very slowly) ; in the subset of numbers with 10 factors, the percentage of winning numbers shoud be small . So, combining these different models, you should obtain something.

Comment: 3 mod 4 have an odd number of 3 mod 4 factors. 5 mod 6 have an odd number of 5 mod 6 factors.

Comment: @ThePhoenix This is precisely it. Pls post is as an answer. I will accept it.